# R function to give me $P(X<x)$

Tags: r, quantiles, cumulative-distribution-function

I have this empirical discrete distribution with the respective percentiles (picture below).
I want to know a R function which gives me $P(X\lt0.58)$ instead of $P(X\le 0.58)$ (given by ECDF function).

The ECDF function gives me around $0.89$ and $0.90$ but I want something between $0.83$ and $0.84$ (see the picture below).

Is there any functions that does this?

[image]

Comment: Hint: how can you use the definition of the cumulative density function to determine the probability in an interval?

Comment: @Sycorax I subtract two cdf's

Answer (score 5):

There is a statistical question here.

Let the cumulative distribution function of a random variable be $F_X$, defined as

$$F_X(x) = \Pr(X \le x).$$

What is wanted is a variant of this with a strict inequality,

$$G_X(x) = \Pr(X \lt x).$$

The two differ when there is a nonzero chance that $X=x.$

Notice that the event $X \lt x$ is the same as the event $-X \gt -x,$ which is the complement of the event $-X \le -x.$  Therefore since the chance of an event and the chance of its complement must sum to unity,

> $$G_X(x) = 1 - \Pr(-X \le -x) = 1 - F_{-X}(-x).$$

In this way we may find $G_X$ without having to do any more programming simply by computing the empirical CDF for the data $-X.$

In `R`, for instance, the empirical distribution $F$ of data `x` would be computed as

```R
f <- ecdf(x)
```

Consequently we may compute $G$ as

```R
g <- function(a) 1 - (ecdf(-x))(-a)
```

**Here is an illustration of the difference** using a dataset much like the one in the question with $x_0=0.58$ the value at which $F_X$ and $G_X$ are to be computed.

[image: Figure]

In this example, $F_X(0.58)=0.9$ while $G_X(0.58)=0.8.$  You can see that $F_X$ gives the height of the solid dot at $x_0$ while $G_X$ gives the height of the dot immediately to its left.

The dataset `x` consists of these 30 numbers:

```
0.24(7) 0.25(2) 0.26 0.27 0.28 0.29(2) 0.30 0.31 0.37 0.39
0.40 0.41 0.44(2) 0.49 0.52 0.58(3) 0.59 0.61 0.78
```

The values in parentheses give the counts of duplicated values.